# How to access a list in another method

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am new to .NET and I would like to be able to solve this small problem that I am facing. I want to access a list that is in Info method to be able to use it in InfoCurricular method. I do not know how I can do it, if I create a method if doing everything in one is the best. The methods are separated because they have different attributes which result in different results after the action taken.

**Info Method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Info(string anoLetivo) {
  var nomeuc = new List<NomeUC>();
  Main main = new Main();
  main.NomeUC = nomeuc;
  //user
  var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
  //docente
  var IDdocente = _context.Docente.SingleOrDefault(x => x.UserId == user.Id);

  var nomeporano = (from nome in _context.NomeUC
    join unidadecurric in _context.UnidadeCurricular on nome.NomeUCId equals unidadecurric.NomeUCId
    join depart in _context.Departamento on unidadecurric.DepartamentoId equals depart.DepartamentoId
    join doc in _context.Docente on depart.DepartamentoId equals doc.DepartamentoId
    join nalunos in _context.NAlunos on unidadecurric.UnidadeCurricularId equals nalunos.UnidadeCurricularId
    join anoletivo in _context.AnoLetivo on nalunos.AnoLetivoId equals anoletivo.AnoLetivoId
    where anoletivo.Ano == anoLetivo && doc.DepartamentoId == IDdocente.DepartamentoId
    select new {
      nome=nome.Nome
    }).ToList();

  foreach (var item in nomeporano) {
    nomeuc.Add(new NomeUC {
      Nome = item.nome
    });
  }

  return View("InfoCurricular", main);
}
```

**InfoCurricular Method**

```
public async Task<IActionResult> InfoCurricular(int ano, int semestre) {
  var nomeuc = new List<NomeUC>();
  //var docente = new List<Docente>();
  var unidadecurr = new List<UnidadeCurricular>();

  Main main = new Main();       
  //main.Docente = docente;
  main.UnidadeCurricular = unidadecurr;
  main.NomeUC = nomeuc;

  //user
  var user = await GetCurrentUserAsync();
  //docente
  var IDdocente = _context.Docente.Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id).ToList();

  var uc = (from nome in *nomeporano*
    join unidadecurric in _context.UnidadeCurricular on nome.NomeUCId equals unidadecurric.NomeUCId
    where unidadecurric.AnoCurricular == ano && unidadecurric.Semestre == semestre
    select new {
        nome = nome.Nome
    }).ToList();

  foreach(var item in uc) {
    nomeuc.Add(new NomeUC {
      Nome = item.nome
    });
  }

  return View(main);
}
```

In the `InfoCurrilar` method in the uc variable I want to use in the query the values of the other list that is in the Info method and from these values get a new list after executing the query.

The idea is not to get the list in the two methods but use the *nomeporano* list as a way of going there to seek values.

But this "nomeporano" have attributes that are different in this two methods. I'm still a little bit confused on how to build the method. In Info method the attribute is one, but in InfoCurricular there are two attributes which is different from the other method. How to build a method to retrieve this "nomeporano" list and use that list in methods Info and InfoCurricular? I can undestrand the ways but i'm stuck on the way to build the method .....

Comment: Extract the shared logic from `InfoCurrilar` into a new method. Call it from both methods that need it.

Comment: What do you mean with extract the shared logic??? I don't understand your idea....

Comment: Create a new function - let's call it `Bob`. Put the shared logic you want inside the `Bob` function. Call `Bob` from both `Info` and `InfoCurricular`. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0s21cwxk.aspx

Comment: But this "nomeporano" have attributes that are different in this two methods. I'm still a little bit confused on how to build the method. In Info method the attribute is one, but in InfoCurricular there are two attributes which is different from the other method. How to build a method to retrieve this "nomeporano" list and use that list in methods Info and InfoCurricular? I can undestrand the ways but i'm stuck on the way to build the method ......

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 ways of doing it:

1.) Add a property in the Model class "Main" for retaining complete value of nomeporano, and since you are passing the model to method InfoCurricular, it can easily be used.

2.) Move the below code in the separate method and call the method in methods Info and InfoCurricular:

Cons: Hitting the database multiple times for same data.

var nomeporano = (from nome in _context.NomeUC
    join unidadecurric in _context.UnidadeCurricular on nome.NomeUCId equals unidadecurric.NomeUCId
    join depart in _context.Departamento on unidadecurric.DepartamentoId equals depart.DepartamentoId
    join doc in _context.Docente on depart.DepartamentoId equals doc.DepartamentoId
    join nalunos in _context.NAlunos on unidadecurric.UnidadeCurricularId equals nalunos.UnidadeCurricularId
    join anoletivo in _context.AnoLetivo on nalunos.AnoLetivoId equals anoletivo.AnoLetivoId
    where anoletivo.Ano == anoLetivo && doc.DepartamentoId == IDdocente.DepartamentoId
    select new {
      nome=nome.Nome
    }).ToList();

Regards,
Rajiv

## Happy Coding

Comment: But this "nomeporano" have attributes that are different in this two methods. I'm still a little bit confused on how to build the method. In Info method the attribute is one, but in InfoCurricular there are two attributes which is different from the other method. How to build a method to retrieve this "nomeporano" list and use that list in methods Info and InfoCurricular? I can undestrand the ways but i'm stuck on the way to build the method ......

Comment: I don't know if i explained correctly but try to saw what i edti on my post.... this what i want to do but i don't know why